# Adding Macros to Parameters (Param1, Param2, etc.) in Assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, macros

I'm having issues finishing an assignment that involves adding macros. After pushing and calling Param1 and Param2 into the M5 (fifth macro) for the dividing function, I ran into an incorrect result and remainder after running it: "The result is 4, and the remainder is -858993460." Other than what I have done so far, I don't know what other steps to do in order to complete the program.

Here are the instructions I was given for the assignment: 
"Modify lab seven such that you will create a macro for each call. The parameters for the macro will be: the function name, parameter1, parameter2, etc. The macro will allow up to five parameters but will use fewer if that is all that are passed to it. Also create macros for the startup of each function (that is a macro to do the push ebp and the mov ebp,esp statements) and for the return from each function (the pop ebp and ret statements)."

Here is the Main.cpp code (it doesn't need to be messed with):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum ResultCode { ShowSquare, ShowMultiply, ShowDivide, ShowRemainder, ShowDivideFailure };
enum SuccessCode { Failure, Success };

extern "C" SuccessCode Divide(long, long, long &, long &);
extern "C" long Multiply(long, long);
extern "C" void PrintResult(ResultCode, long);
extern "C" long Square(long);

void main()
{
    long Num1;
    long Num2;
    long Result;
    long Remainder;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Number to Square. " << endl;
        cin >> Num1;
        Result = Square(Num1);
        cout << "Square is: " << Result << endl;
        cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply. " << endl;
        cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
        Result = Multiply(Num1, Num2);
        cout << "Result of multiply is: " << Result << endl;
        cout << "Enter a mumber to divide into, then a number to divide by. " << endl;
        cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
        if (Divide(Num1, Num2, Result, Remainder) == Success)
            cout << "The result is " << Result << ", and the remainder is " << Remainder << "." << endl;
        else
            cout << "Attempted division by zero. ";
    } while (Result > 0);
}
void PrintResult(ResultCode PrintCode, long Value)
{
    switch (PrintCode)
    {
    case ShowSquare:
        cout << "Display of square is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowMultiply:
        cout << "Display of multiply is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowDivide:
        cout << "Display of divide is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowRemainder:
        cout << "Display of remainder is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowDivideFailure:
        cout << "Display of Division by zero" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error in assembly routines. " << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the Asm.asm file:

```
.386

.model flat

public _Square
public _Multiply
public _Divide
extern  _PrintResult:proc

Param1 = 4          ; creates a named constant, only works with whole numbers

Param1 = 8          ; names can be redefined
Param2 = 16
Param3 = 24
Param4 = 32
Param5 = 40

M1      macro
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        endm

M2      macro   P1
        pop     P1
        ret
        endm

M3      macro   P1:REQ, P2          ;; :REQ means the parameter is required
IFB <P2>
P1      BYTE    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
ELSE
P1      P2      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
ENDIF
        endm

M4      macro   P1, P2
LOCAL   L1, L2
        cmp     P1, P2
        jl      L1
        inc     P1
        jmp     L2
L1:     inc     P2
L2:
        endm

M5      macro   Param1, Param2
        push [Param1]
        push [Param2]
    ;   push [Param3]
    ;   push [Param4]
    ;   push [Param5]
        Call    Param1
        Call    Param2
    ;   Call    Param3
    ;   Call    Param4
    ;   Call    Param5
        add ebp, 8
        endm

.code

_Square proc
       M1
       finit
       mov eax, [ebp + 8]
       imul eax
       M2 ebp
       ret
_Square endp

_Multiply proc
       M1
       finit
       mov eax, [ebp + 8]
       mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
       imul ebx
       M2 ebp
       ret
_Multiply endp

_Divide proc
       M1
       finit
       mov eax, [ebp + 8]
       mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
       mov ecx, [ebp + 16]
       mov edx, 0
       idiv ebx
       mov ecx, eax
       mov ebx, [ebp + 20]
       mov ebx, edx
    ;   M5 ebp, esp
    ;   Call    _PrintResult
    ;   add ebp, 8
       M2 ebp
       M5 ebp, esp
       ret
_Divide endp

.data

db  255

end
```

Comment: Where do you assign value to P2 ?
I think you reminder is `-858993460`, because some variable isn't initialized before using.

Comment: @V.Panchenko P2 was assigned for M3 and M4.

Comment: I tried to bring P2 into the division proc, but nothing good came of it. I don't think they belong there.

Comment: Your M2 macro issues `ret` instruction. Calling M5 after M2 is meaningless in your _divide proc. All `ret` instructions after M2 are meaningless. Also as your M2 pops only `ebp`, there is no need to pass it in a parameter. Your M5 should call procedure and you're passing registers as parameters...